# I keep getting 404 not found on gulp serve?

Tags: sharepoint-framework

Request URL:https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-property-pane/node_modules/react/dist/react.js
Request Method:GET
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4321
Status Code:
404

I modified a file locally and then I got the error, but now I keep getting the same error when I revert everything on gulp serve. Is it possible there's another process running? What might be causing this problem?

```
***CALLSTACK:
SPError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:24453:24
SPLoaderError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:42171:28
ff4n/ErrorBuilder</ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46165:21
ff4n/ErrorBuilder</ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:46034:21
_loadComponentImpl/<@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:45372:75
```

Comment: Have you stopped and re-run `gulp serve`?  I have found that sometimes adding new files, or switching code branches confuses the running gulp service, but a simple cancel and re-run the command usually fixes it.

Comment: try aborting the serve, then running 'gulp clean'. After this, run 'gulp build' -- do you get any errors?